# OnClick function is not working in IE 10, but fine in older versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Within a standard Dot.Net application there is an option to add buttons, which can do certain functions.

This button, when clicked, opens Google in a new window with an input parameter from the current window.

```
<button class="exButton" language="VBS" onclick="MakeReq()">Search Google</button>
&nbsp;
<script language="VBS"> 
    Sub MakeReq() 
        window.open "https://www.google.nl/?gws_rd=ssl#q=" & frmMain.FreeTextField_01.Value 
    End Sub
</script>
```

The button works fine in IE9 or in IE10 in compatibility mode. 
However on Chrome or IE 10 it does not function. I get no response or visible error.

Does anyone know:

1. Why it fails to function in IE10?
2. More importantly how I can adjust to code to get it working again?

Please keep in mind I can only influence this small piece of script as the rest of the page is controlled by the supplier of the application.

Comment: Change VBScript to javascript, VBscript is not supported in modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Move to javascript, something like this:

```
<button class="exButton" onclick="MakeReq()">Search Google</button>
&nbsp;
<script language="text/javascript"> 
    function MakeReq() {

        frmMain = document.forms[0]; // if it is the first form
        textField = frmMain.elements["FreeTextField_01"];

        window.open("https://www.google.nl/?gws_rd=ssl#q="+textField.value;
    }
</script>
```

But it's not cleat what is frmMain.FreeTextField_01.value, so I tried to imagine it is a field in the first form in the page.

Other ways could be:

```
textField = document.getElementsByName("FreeTextField_01")[0];
```

or

```
frmMain = document.forms["frmMain"];
textField = frmMain.elements["FreeTextField_01"];
```

or

```
frmMain = document.forms[0]; // if it is the first form
textField = frmMain.elements[0]; // if it is the first form element
```

or

```
frmMain = document.getElementById("frmMain");
textField = frmMain.elements["FreeTextField_01"];
```

if the form has an id="frmMain"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help! Below is what ended up working for me.

```
 <button class="exButton" onclick="myFunction()">Google Search</button> 
 <script language="text/javascript"> 
       function myFunction() 
          { 
           frmMain = document.getElementById("frmMain"); 
           textField = frmMain.elements["FreeTextField_01"]; 

           window.open("google.nl/?gws_rd=ssl#q="+textField.value); 
          } 
</script>
```